# Angular2 rxjs map() after mapped function completes subscribe handle

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get a better handle on RXJS but I am getting a `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when I call AudienceService.addAudience().

The problem seems to be that when a token refresh is required, the `AudienceService` tries to map to the `AuthHttpService.post()` before the subscription within the `AuthHttpService.post()` is completed.

How can I code for this, and ensure that the `map()` only executes after the `AuthHttpService` is done refreshing the token?

AudienceService that maps to AuthHttpService.post:

```
addAudience(model: AddDeleteAudienceModel) {
    return this.authHttpService.post(this.baseApiUrl + 'audience', JSON.stringify(model)).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

AuthHttpService with a POST method:

```
post(endpoint: string, body: string) {
    if (this.authService.tokenRequiresRefresh()) {
      this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(true);
      this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.authService.refreshTokenSuccessHandler(data);
          // The audience service post call returns "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
          console.log("User is now logged in");
          if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
            this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
            return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
          } else {
            this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
            this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);
          }
        },
        error => {
          this.authService.refreshTokenErrorHandler(error);
          Observable.throw(error);
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      console.log("HTTP Post token refresh not required.");
      return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
    }
  }
```

Comment: and you imported this from  from 'RxJs' ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh yes, map itself is imported, and the issue ONLY occurs when a token refresh is required, otherwise map is defined.

Comment: What is authHttpService?

Comment: @chrigu I kind of understand what you are saying, but if possible, can you provide an example of how to get it to work?  The goal here is for the `subscribe()` to finish before anything is returned.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat think of it simple as the angular2 Http service, returns an Observable.  What it does on top of that is put the user's token in the requests.

Comment: @blgrnboy I see your problem. Post is wrong few mins

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat thank you!  I will wait for the official answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned correctly `post()` won't return anything when it needs to refresh the token. The `return` statement in the `subscribe()` method won't be called as the function returns before the token is refreshed.

You shoud use the `switchMap()` instead of the `subscribe` call. In this case you also need to return an Observable from within the else block. Like so:

```
post(endpoint: string, body: string) {
    if (this.authService.tokenRequiresRefresh()) {
      this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(true);
      return this.authService.refreshToken().switchMap(
        data => {
          this.authService.refreshTokenSuccessHandler(data);
          // The audience service post call returns "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
          console.log("User is now logged in");
          if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
            this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
            return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
          } else {
            this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
            this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);
            // return an Observable here otherwise you also get an undefined
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.authService.refreshTokenErrorHandler(error);
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
    }
    else {
      console.log("HTTP Post token refresh not required.");
      return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
    }
  }
```

More about [`switchMap()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html). It will basically map the values from the inner Observable to the outer Observable.

Comment: I like this solution, but it seems to return the following error:

Module build failed: Error: C:/src/USB.EnterpriseAutomation.AuthApi.UI/src/app/services/auth-http.service.ts (38,3): No best common type exists among return expressions.)

Comment: @blgrnboy does`this.postInternal(endpoint, body)` return an Observable?

Comment: In else you probably need to throw exception after  this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Yeah, maybe you should do that.

Comment: @blgrnboy I guess the error block should also return some kind of Observable. Does TS also complain if you remove (just for testing) the error block?

Comment: If I set the return type of post to : Observable<any>, it is able to build the module.

It seems that it added the token, but it executed `data =>` as well as `error =>`.  Perhaps switchmap shouldn't have an error handler?

Comment: @blgrnboy I guess you're right. Try to add a `catch` block on the [outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754106/angular2-rxjs-switchmap-catch-error)

Answer (score 1):

In Post you need to return observable. I am not sure 100% that this works but idea is that you create observable and return it, than inside you do you logic. You can emit next, or throw exception

```
post(endpoint: string, body: string) {
    if (this.authService.tokenRequiresRefresh()) {
        this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(true);
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.authService.refreshTokenSuccessHandler(data);
                    // The audience service post call returns "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
                    console.log("User is now logged in");
                    if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
                        this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
                        this.postInternal(endpoint, body).subscribe(resp => {
                            observer.next(resp);
                        })

                    } else {
                        this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
                        this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);
                        observer.error(error);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    this.authService.refreshTokenErrorHandler(error);
                    observer.error(error);
                }
            );
        });


    }
    else {
        console.log("HTTP Post token refresh not required.");
        return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
    }
}
```

I have tested as part of my app

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
        (<Promise<string>>token)
          .then((tAsString) => {
            super.request(this.getRequestOptionArgs(tAsString, request))
              .subscribe(response => {
                observer.next(response);
                // this emit error observer.error(eror)
              })

          })
      });
```

PS. But I thing switchMap is better option :)

Comment: It works, however, it seems to somewhat prematurely return I think.  I have a refresh of all audiences in my subscription to `addAudience`, and that refresh doesn't catch the add.  On the next refresh, it does.

Comment: I didn't get it can you please explain :)