# Angular2 rxjs - switchmap catch error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'd like to be able to handle any errors that error when calling `this.authService.refreshToken()`.  Can errors be handled within the switchmap block, or how do I go about handling an error in this case?

```
post3(endpoint: string, body: string) : Observable<any> {
    if (this.authService.tokenRequiresRefresh()) {
      this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(true);
      return this.authService.refreshToken().switchMap(
        data => {
          this.authService.refreshTokenSuccessHandler(data);
          if (this.authService.loggedIn()) {
            this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
            return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
          } else {
            this.authService.tokenIsBeingRefreshed.next(false);
            this.router.navigate(['/sessiontimeout']);
            Observable.throw(data);
          }
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      return this.postInternal(endpoint, body);
    }
  }
```

Comment: BTW, you need a return: `return Observable.throw(data);`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use the [catchError](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) method

```
this.authService.refreshToken()
  .pipe(
     switchMap(() => {...}),
     catchError((e) => {
       // handle e and return a safe value or re-throw
       if (isCritical(e)) {
         return throwError(e);
       }
       return of([]);
    })
  );
```

Comment: This method was [renamed to `catchError` in v6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax).

Comment: thanks @AlexPeters, I updated the example to use the latest api.